# how to call javascript function use src tag

Tags: javascript

how to call javascript functions in "src" tag

I am using this but script wont show.

```
<div class="name1">Hello</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/wp-content/themes/thejava.js"> </script>
```

the .js file i using

```
 var random=new Array(); 
    random[0]='Mom'; 
    random[1]='Dad'; 
var id=Math.round(Math.random()*(random.length-1)); document.write(random[id]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example works. Perhaps you are not properly linking the script element? Open chrome's developer tools (f12) and see if the script is failing to load

```html
<div class="name1">Hello</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var random=new Array(); 
    random[0]='Mom'; 
    random[1]='Dad'; 
var id=Math.round(Math.random()*(random.length-1)); document.write(random[id]);
</script>
```